# Linq Entities Query Compare days of Dates

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table that save users birthday, I want to find Users who are born today.

```
 _db.BirthdayReminders.Where(m => DbFunctions.DiffDays(m.Birthday,today.Date)==0 && ).ToList();
```

But  find this year's birthday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about simply checking the `Day` and `Month`?:

```
_db.BirthdayReminders
    .Where(m => m.Birthday.Day == today.Day && m.Birthday.Month == today.Month)
    .ToList();
```

I'm not sure how you want to handle people born on the 29th of February. Apparently some celebrate their birthdays on the 28th of February, and others on the 1st of March. I'm not sure how you would want to handle that.

My advice in that scenario would be something like (if you celebrated their birthday on the 28th of February):

1. Determine if it's a leap year. If it's not, proceed to 2.
2. Determine if their birthday is the 29th of February, and then either evaluate `true` on the 28th of February, or 1st of March, or both.

Which could be written as:

```
_db.BirthdayReminders
    .Where(m => (m.Birthday.Day == today.Day && m.Birthday.Month == today.Month)
        || (!isLeapYear && m.Birthday.Day == 29 && m.Birthday.Month == 2 && today.Day == 28 && today.Month == 2))
    .ToList();
```